# How to share location on Facebook along with message using https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to use iOS SLRequest and graph API "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed" ,..for posting a message with the location on Facebook wall ?

I have implemented SLRequest as below,

```
                        SLRequest *feedRequest = [SLRequest
                                               requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                               requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                               URL:https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
                                               parameters:@{@"message": @"text message with location",@"link":@"www.google.com",@"place":@"Road No 19, Mumbai"}];
```

with                                       ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream",
                                                                  @"publish_actions"],
returns 500 status error.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there more info aside from just a 500 error? Your "place" parameter is not a valid one. It needs to be the ID of a place page, not just an address. See the <user_id>/feed documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed

Comment: @Ming Li - There is no error,but just the response status is 500. And regarding the <user_id>/feed documentation you have referred above, can you suggest an sample code snippet as to how can I get the ID of place page.

Comment: To get the id of a place page, supposed you wanted the id of the Space Needle in Seattle, here's the Facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/spaceneedle, just replace the 'www' with 'graph', and make a request to https://graph.facebook.com/spaceneedle and you'll see an 'id' property.

Comment: @user2020789 have you found solution to this problem ? if yes then can you post the code ?

Answer (score 0):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a "server-side" error, meaning the problem is not with your PC or Internet connection but instead is a problem with the web site's server.

**Use this to integrate in your code to share location**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/placepicker-ui-control/

Use this method to post feed:-

```
-(IBAction)postFBMessage:(id)sender
{
    // Create the URL to the end point
    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

    NSString *link = @"http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233";
    NSString *message = @"Testing Social Framework";
    NSString *picture = @"http://www.stuarticus.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/SDKsmall.png";
    NSString *name = @"Social Framework";
    NSString *caption = @"Reference Documentation";
    NSString *description = @"The Social framework lets you integrate your app with supported social networking services. On iOS and OS X, this framework provides a template for creating HTTP requests. On iOS only, the Social framework provides a generalized interface for posting requests on behalf of the user.";

    NSDictionary *postDict = @{
    @"link": link,
    @"message" : message,
    @"picture" : picture,
    @"name" : name,
    @"caption" : caption,
    @"description" : description
    };

    SLRequest *postToMyWall = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:postURL parameters:postDict];

    FacebookAccountManager* sharedManager = [FacebookAccountManager sharedAccount];
    [postToMyWall setAccount:sharedManager.facebookAccount];

    [postToMyWall performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error) {
            // If there is an error we populate the error string with error
            _errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [error localizedDescription]];

            // We then perform the UI update on the main thread. All UI updates must be completed on the main thread.
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateErrorString) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Post successful");
            NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
            NSLog(@"Response Data: %@", dataString);
        }
     }];
}
```

Comment: ,I have used the your above suggested method to post a feed but what my actual requirement was to send a location (or place) as  parameter along with other parameters like (link, message) for /me/feed API.