# Share location on Facebook wall using Social framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am trying to integrate Sharing on Facebook Login in my application but somehow i am not able to achieve this for sharing the location on the Facebook wall, here i am using the social framework.

The code i tried is as follows :

```
SLComposeViewController *fbController=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

            [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

            switch(result){
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                default:
                {
                    NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");
                    // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
                    }
                    break;
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                {
                    NSLog(@"Posted....");
                }
                    break;
            }};
        [fbController setInitialText:@"This is My Sample Text"];
        [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
        [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sign in!" message:@"Please first Sign In!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

by this I can share the Initial text but what i need is to share is the current location.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Want to use graph API?[check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329083/how-to-share-location-on-facebook-along-with-message-using-https-graph-faceboo)

Comment: @UmangBista have you understood the question?

Comment: You want: 
'Text to post'— feeling thankful at 'location' ?

Comment: yes, and the "location" will be my current location. and the link you just gave doesn't explain about sharing the location. its all text part.

Comment: Agent, SLComposeViewController already has a functionality to include user's location. See this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/afUxS.png What else do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

u can get current location using CLLocationManger as for this import MapKit framework.

```
NSString  *city;
CLLocationManager *locationManager;

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [locationManager.location coordinate];
GeoCodeValue=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude];
NSLog(@"userLocation::%@",GeoCodeValue);

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    city = placemark.thoroughfare;
}];
```

& pass this city string as text to show current location.as

```
 [fbController setInitialText:@"Current Location is %@",city"];
```